# Google Kickstart Wandering Robot wrong answer

Tags: c++, algorithm

Hi I wrote a short program to try to answer Google Kickstart 2020 Round B problem Wandering Robot. I essentially tried to implement the analysis provided by Google, and my solution seems to work on all the sample cases I've tried, but it never passes Google's first test set.

Here's my code, and below it the problem description and a short explanation of my approach. What I really want to know is what I'm doing wrong, why I'm not passing the first test set, more than anything.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include<math.h>
using namespace std; 
#include <iomanip> 
    
int W, H, L, U, R, D;
    
const int len = 100000;
double facts [len];

void factorial(){
    
    facts[0] = log2(1);
    
    for(int i=2; i<= len; i++){
        facts[i-1] = log2(i) + facts[i-2];
    }
}

bool impossible(){
    
    if((L==1 && R==W) || (U==1 && D==H)){
        return true;
    }
    
    return false;
}


double pass(int x, int y, int s, int t, int i){
    
    double num = log2(x+y);
    num = facts[x+y-1];
    
    double prob = x+y;
    double tot = 0; 
    double comb = 0; 
    
    //cout << x << " " << s << " " << y << " " << t << endl;
    
    while(x!=s && y!=t){
        
        double denom = facts[x-1] + facts[y-1];
        comb = num -  denom - prob;
        // cout << num << endl;
        tot += pow(2, comb);
        x+=i;
        y-=i;
    }
    
    //lower diagonal, hit the bottom
    //x+1 = number of moves it takes
    //to hit last square
    if(y==H){
       double p = pow(2,comb);
       tot -= p;
       x-=i; 
       
       for(int j=1; j<=x; j++){
           p -= pow(0.5, prob);
           p += pow(0.5, prob-j-1);
       }
       
       tot += p; 
    }
    //upper diagonal, hit the right side
    else if(x==W){
        double p = pow(2,comb);
        tot -= pow(2, comb);
        y+=i;
        
        for(int j=1; j<=y; j++){
           p -= pow(0.5, prob);
           p += pow(0.5, prob-j-1);
       }
       
       tot += p;
    }
    
    return tot;
}

int main() {
    
    int t;
    cin >> t; // read t. cin knows that t is an int, so it reads it as such.
    
    for (int i = 1; i <= t; ++i) {
        
        cin >> W >> H >> L >> U >> R >> D; 
        double tot = 0;
        
        if(impossible()){
            cout << "Case #" << i << ": 0.0" << endl;
        }
        //upper diagonal
        else if(L==1 || D==H){ 
            factorial();
            tot = pass(R, U-2, W, -1, 1);
            cout << "Case #" << i << ": " <<  fixed << setprecision(9) << tot << endl;
        }
        //lower diagonal 
        else if(R==W || U==1){ 
            factorial();
            tot = pass(L-2, D, -1, H, -1);
            cout << "Case #" << i << ": " <<  fixed << setprecision(9) << tot << endl;
        }
        //symmetric
        else if(D==R && L==U){
            factorial();
            tot = pass(R, U-2, W, -1, 1);
            tot *=2;
            cout << "Case #" << i << ": " <<  fixed << setprecision(9) << tot << endl;
          }
          //call count both
          else{ 
            factorial();
            tot = pass(R, U-2, W, -1, 1);  
            tot += pass(L-2, D,-1, H, -1);
            cout << "Case #" << i << ": " <<  fixed << setprecision(9) << tot << endl;
          }
      }
      return 0;
    }
```

[image]

The way that I tried to solve it was to find the probability of passing through the green squares and the reciprocal squares spanning from the upper right corner of the hole to the right edge of the arena.

[image: Two green]

Comment: Stopped reading here: `int W, H, L, U, R, D;` Single letter variables are just asking for problems.

Comment: @user4581301 the variables are named according to the problem prompt. Coming up with different names than the one provided by the problem prompt seems counterintuitive.

Comment: I suggest that you print the grid, and fill in the probabilities by hand, starting from the upper left. There *is* a pattern to the probabilities that allows you to directly compute the probability at any grid coordinate. I would also move X up by one square, and Y up by two squares. Compute the probabilities at those new X and Y positions, call them p(newX) and p(newY). Then the probabilities just below the new X and Y are `p(newX) / 2` and `p(newY) / 2`

Comment: Basically, filling the grid is a O(n^2) method. Not sure it is efficient enough for the 2nd test case set, n = 10^5